# checkbox not rendering correctly when using iCheck. have to trigger checkbox twice

Tags: javascript, icheck

I am trying to use the iCheck checkbox to beautify my normal checkbox. The ajax action in the code triggers recalculation of some data in the backend and gets the new data for the frontend. Afterwards the html is rerendered to show the new data. This part is already working with the normal checkbox. When adding iCheck it still works, but sometimes the rerender causes to show the old html. Sometimes it works on the first time, but often i need to check the box 2 times. When failing on the first click, it always works when i trigger it the second time. 
I cant figure out, why this happens. Its not about clicking the checkbox too fast. I already checked that.

Heres the code:

```
<tr class="abc">
    <td class="description">
        <div class="foo">
            <div class="form-item-checkbox clearfix">
                <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkboxid"
                    styleClass="form-checkbox" value="#{valueToInitializeFromBackend}">
                    <f:ajax event="click" render="@none" execute="@this"
                        listener="#{action.ajax(ciid,'setStuffInBEAndRerenderFE')}" />
                </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>


 $(document).ready(function(){
   var bar = $('.bar');
                var abc = $('.abc');

                abc.find('.foo input')
                        .on('ifChecked', function () {
                            $(this).click();
                        })
                        .on('ifUnchecked', function () {
                            $(this).click();
                        });            
 });




 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input').iCheck({
        checkboxClass   : 'form-checkbox',
        radioClass      : 'form-radio'
        });

        $('button[type="reset"]').click(function(){
            $(this).closest('form').find('input').iCheck('uncheck');
        });
});
```